# Need help using ((ImageView) findViewById.getView().(R.id.imageView1)).setImageBitmap(bmp); in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, findviewbyid

I'm having trouble using the following code in a fragment activity:

```
((ImageView) findViewById.getView().(R.id.imageView1)).setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

I've tried using:

```
((ImageView) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

but this doesn't work. App crashes

Comment: the first is completely wrong. Where are you running the second one?

Comment: Where are you using this methods? Have you tried creating a global reference to your view?

Comment: I'm running the code in an emulator. I'm not too familiar with the creating gobal refernce to view approach, but I'm going to look it up and see if it works

Comment: @Sadio if you want people to continue to answer questions for you, you may want to start picking the "Best" answer and/or indicate what solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

if its imageView1 is in main Activity layout than try this

```
 ImageView myImg=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    myImg.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

if not then

```
ImageView myImg=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    myImg.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

view may be same as place main layout content or after inflate so as per inflate view may change into linearlayout or relativelayout or View.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a fragment then I would advise you to to your assignment in the `onCreateView`method after creating your view for your fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        Bitmap bmp;//<= retrieve/create your bitmap here
        ImageView image =((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1));
        image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        return rootView;
}
```